# Haskell - Parse Error on Input `|" in GHC

Tags: haskell

I've just started programming in Haskell and to get used to the syntax and general style of the language I've decided to try and solve some basic problems on Project Euler.

However, when I tried to compile my code for Problem 1 in GHC, I received an error:

```
main = do

    sum :: Int -> Int
    sum n
        | n == 0         = 0
        | n `mod` 3 == 0 = n + sum (n - 1)
        | n `mod` 5 == 0 = n + sum (n - 1)
        | otherwise      = sum (n - 1)

    print sum 1000
```

The error message in question:

```
Problem1.hs:5:9: error: parse error on input `|'
  |
5 |         | n == 0 = 0
  |         ^
```

Other users having this or a similar problem here usually had something syntactically simple wrong with their code, such as having typed `==` instead of `=`, or had an indentation error, but I don't know why my code doesn't compile properly.
I don't believe it is related to indentation; I am using VSCode and my tab size is set to 4 spaces, but I have also tried indenting manually by using space, both of which produced the same error.

Comment: Functions cannot be defined in a do-block, either put them on the top level or in a `let-in`/`where`.

Comment: Thank you! I should add that my code also had a syntax error, as `print sum 1000` should have been `print (sum 1000)`, nevermind the fact that `sum` is already a pre-defined function, so I had to change the name too.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question, while showing what you came up with. You'll get some free reputation along the way to get you started, and of course, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: You can also use the low precedence function call operator, that is the dollar: `print $ mySum 1000`. See doc [here](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28%24%29&scope=set%3Astackage)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Caramiriel rightfully corrected me, functions cannot be defined in a do-block. I solved this by simply pulling `sum` out of main, but this left 2 problems in the code:

1. The function name `sum` is ambiguous, as it could refer both to the automatically imported function `Prelude.sum`, or the one I created. To solve this, I simply changed my function name to `mySum`.
2. `print mySum 1000` does not compile, as this is equivalent to `print (mySum) 1000`, where both `mySum` and `1000` are inputs for `print`. To fix this, I simply added parentheses: `print (mySum 1000)`

On a less important note, I misread the original question on Project Euler, and it should be `print (mySum 999)` instead. This leaves me with the following (working!) code:

```
mySum :: Int -> Int
mySum n
    | n == 0         = 0
    | n `mod` 3 == 0 = n + mySum (n - 1)
    | n `mod` 5 == 0 = n + mySum (n - 1)
    | otherwise      = mySum (n - 1)

main = do
    print (mySum 999)
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, functions *can* be defined in a `do` block, but you must use a `let` statement, so the following would work fine:

```
main = do
    let sum :: Int -> Int
        sum n
            | n == 0         = 0
            | n `mod` 3 == 0 = n + sum (n - 1)
            | n `mod` 5 == 0 = n + sum (n - 1)
            | otherwise      = sum (n - 1)
    print $ sum 1000
```

As a matter of style, though, it's unusual to define functions within a `do` block unless they *have* to be defined there (because they make reference to a variable defined within the `do`-block, for example), or if they're obviously utility or convenience functions that wouldn't make sense to use outside the `do` block.